# Java 8 apply list of functions on list of values

Tags: java-8, functional-programming, java-stream

Task: we`ve got list of mappers, which must be applied on list of arguments.
How we can do?:

My not really good variant:

```
public static final Function<List<IntUnaryOperator>, UnaryOperator<List<Integer>>> multifunctionalMapper =
    lst -> {
        UnaryOperator<List<Integer>> uOp = new UnaryOperator<List<Integer>>() {
            @Override
            public List<Integer> apply(List<Integer> integers) {
                final int[] curFunct = new int[1];
                List<Integer> newLst = integers;
                for (int i = 0; i < lst.size(); i++) {
                    curFunct[0] = i;
                    newLst = newLst.stream().map(curInt -> lst.get(curFunct[0]).applyAsInt(curInt)).collect(Collectors.toList());
                }
                return newLst;
            }
        };
        return uOp;
    };
```

list of mappers addOneMuxTwoTransformation:

```
public static final UnaryOperator<List<Integer>> addOneMuxTwoTransformation =
        multifunctionalMapper.apply(Arrays.asList(x -> x+1, x -> x*2));
```

**test:**

```
addOneMuxTwoTransformation.apply(Arrays.asList(1,2,3)).stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```

**will print:**

```
4
6
8
```

**How can be multifunctionalMapper's code reduced?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**next solution is**

```
public static final Function<List<IntUnaryOperator>, UnaryOperator<List<Integer>>> multifunctionalMapper =lstFunc->
         lstVals -> lstVals.stream()
        .map(curValue -> lstFunc.stream().reduce(IntUnaryOperator::andThen).orElse(x -> x).applyAsInt(curValue))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what are you trying to do ?

```
List<IntUnaryOperator> ops = Arrays.asList(a -> a++, a -> a*2);
IntUnaryOperator reduce = ops.stream().reduce(a -> a, IntUnaryOperator::andThen);

IntStream.of(1, 2, 3).map(reduce).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: but each time, yout need a function, you need to produce, CustomOps and CustomReduce. My solution ONCE Reduce, then each time implement CustomOps. See "next solution is" - that is OnceReduce.